# Javascript file causing Ionic app to crash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-cache

I'm trying to create a new angular service for my Ionic app, however the new javascript file is 'mysteriously' causing the app to behave inappropriately, for e.g. when I call the `$cordova.getDevice()` method it returns me the results that would usually get from call `CacheFactory.get("cache_key")`.

I tried removing all the code from the file, even with the code there were error reported in the console, I tried changing the name of the service.Although there is barely any code in the .js file, it still causes the app to crash.

The only thing that works is removing the completely removing the file reference from the index.html file, thereafter the app behaves normally.

Here's the angular service:

```
function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('starter').factory('TokenService', ['$http', '$q', '$ionicLoading', 'StringService', TokenService]);

function TokenService($http, $q, $ionicLoading, StringService){

}
})();
```

As mentioned previously, even with the little code it has, it still causes issues.

Comment: Could you post you error message ?

Comment: TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'length'
    at Object.n.start (file:///android_asset/www/js/forge.min.js:1:49331)
    at Object.e.exports.a.pbkdf2.n.pbkdf2 [as pbkdf2] (file:///android_asset/www/js/forge.min.js:1:101770)
    at Object.encrypt_message [as encrypt] (file:///android_asset/www/app/services/cipherService.js:9:35)
    at file:///android_asset/www/app/login/login-ctrl.js:23:52
    at processQueue (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29132:28)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29148:27

Comment: That error is most likely occuring because the data that's supposed to be in the cache is not there, which is the device details, reason why its not the right data in cache is because when I call `$cordova.getDevice()` the result of this is instead `CacheFactory.get("some_key")` as mentioned previously but the error message has nothing to do with angular thats what makes it even more confusing.